# Call to function by using argument on python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the proper way to use **kwargs in Python to call function and get the output from script?
I will like to use the script like that:

```
python script.py <argument> "here description"
```

Here my example

```
class Task:
    pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        arguments = {'cre': 'create', 'inf': 'info', 'sre': 'search', 'com': 'comment'}
        arguments.update(kwargs)
        self.create = arguments['cre']
        self.action = arguments['inf']
        self.search = arguments['sre']
        self.comment = arguments['com']

    def create(description):
         print "Task in progress -->-->"

    def search(description):
        print "Searching for task"

    def info(description):
        print "Task Info"

    def comment(description):
        print "Comment task"

if __name__=='__main__':
    Task(**kwargs)
```

On current script i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_function.py", line 39, in <module>
    Task(**kwargs)
NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined
```

Comment: You can get command line arguments from `sys.argv`

Comment: `Task(**kwargs)`: in this line there are are no kwargs yet, `sys.argv` does give you command-line arguments, but as a list, not a dict, so more processing is needed

Comment: You can't get argument names from command line like this. Maybe you should look into [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import sys

class Task(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        functions_mapping = {
            'cre': self.create,
            'inf': self.info,
            'sre': self.search,
            'com': self.comment
        }

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.description = value
            try:
                functions_mapping.get(key)()
            except TypeError:
                print "Please provide a correct function name: {}".format(', '.join([x for x in functions_mapping.keys()]))

    def create(self):
        print "Task in progress --> {}".format(self.description)

    def search(self):
        print "Searching for task --> {}".format(self.description)

    def info(self):
        print "Task Info --> {}".format(self.description)

    def comment(self):
        print "Comment task --> {}".format(self.description)


if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and len(sys.argv) < 4:
        function, description = sys.argv[1:]
        my_dict = dict()
        my_dict[function] = description
        Task(**my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
➜  python stackoverflow.py com something_here
Comment task --> something_here

➜  python stackoverflow.py inf something_else
Task Info --> something_else

➜  python stackoverflow.py sre something_more
Searching for task --> something_more

➜  python stackoverflow.py cre somethingggggg
Task in progress --> somethingggggg

➜  python stackoverflow.py moo foobar
Please provide a correct function name: inf, sre, com, cre
```

Comment: Syntax error:

`
Task(args[0]=args[1])
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
`

Comment: @Robert I've updated my answer

Comment: `with print(Task(**my_dict)) I get:
<__main__.Task instance at 0x7f02829b1a28>` Instead name of argument and description-text

Comment: @Robert You don't need to print like that. If you want to test my code just add `print arguments` under `arguments.update(kwargs)`

Comment: ok, but how I can get output from chosen function as argument?

Comment: @Robert I've updated my answer again

Comment: Andrés, This is precisely what I need, thank you for you help.

Comment: @Robert that's good to know. It's my pleasure!